# Cypress doesn't recognize icon code correctly

Tags: cypress

I'm writing test in `Cypress` to test if icon in `'a:before'` pseudo element is correct.

The `'a:before'` icon code is `\f115`, but `Cypress` sees it as ``.
As a result my assert fails with

```
AssertionError: expected '""' to equal '"\f115"'.
```

Why does `Cypress` see `\f115` as ``?